# Visual Studio 2017 + TFS - Problemas de Desempenho

Tags: visual-studio, team-foundation-server

Tenho uma instalação do VS 2017 usando TFS como controle de versão, e quando estou fazendo *merge* de um *branch* com outro, leva muito tempo para carregar os detalhes do *changeset*.

Alguém já teve esse tipo de problema? Sabem como resolver?

Comment: Usa NuGet? O `tfsignore` ignora os diretórios das bibliotecas do NuGet?

Comment: Outras operações no Source Control ocorrem normalmente?

Comment: Ismael, outras operações ocorrem normalmente. E o problema ocorre apenas de uma branch específica pra outra específica (temos três). Cigano, usamos, vou observar isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os Merges ocorrem sempre na máquina client, normalmente quem usa TFVC está usando o Visual Studio para isso. O processo ao qual você se refere parece mais com o upload do código para o servidor, ou seja o check-in.

Além de verificar o "peso" do merge que você está fazendo, grandes merges costumam demorar mais, por isso faça pequenos incrementos de código, reveja a sua estratégia de branch; verifique a saúde do servidor do TFS: uso de CPU, memória disponível, ...

É preciso verificar também:

- O servidor é dedicado ao TFS?
- Como está a saúde do banco de dados?

Comment: Não é o processo de check-in. É o processo onde eu busco os changesets para realizar o merge. Sim, é um servidor dedicado para o TFS.

Comment: É uma base de código antiga? Tem binários? Sabe dizer o tamanho da base toda?